# angularjs radiobutton groups having its own model

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angular-ngmodel

I want to create a a 3 radio button groups each having its own unique model using one ng-repeat.    How can I achieve this?

```
<div  class="radio" data-ng-repeat="item in selItem.items" >
                <label class="control-label">
                  <input type="radio" 
                  data-ng-value={{item.vm}}  
                  data-ng-model="????"
                  name="{{selItem.Title}}"/>{{item.dm}} 
                   </label>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, why would you do that? Radio buttons are for a unique selection among a group of options, so having the same model for all radio buttons is the way to go.

However, for setting unique `ng-model`s for each item iteration inside `ng-repeat`, you have to use object bracket notation, using `$index` or a property of each iteration itself to name the property of the object model.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myModel[item.name]" >
</div>
```

check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daslaf/vzkttd3j/) to see it working

Comment: Our UI is unique that, backend passes what kind of controller should be displayed on UI, depending on that how many ever those type of controller are there, those should get rendered. So in one scenario backend says render me a display with 3 components(meaning 3 different fields) where are the 3 are radio buttons